# How do I keep the mergExt Banner control from covering the tab bar at the bottom of an IOS device

Tags: ios, livecode

I am just getting started with using `MergExt` and I am unsure how keep the iAd banner from covering my `Tab Bar` at the bottom of the IOS display? Additionally is it possible to manually move its position to any other location on the screen in case it covers any other controls? I have tried looking about for information but havent found much on the subject and I have tried playing with setting the rectangle to no avail. any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

mergBanner displays the banner at the bottom of your screen. What many people do is align the tab bar to the top of the banner and use the area below to display a static ad/image until the iAd is loaded. There's currently no options for setting the rect of placing the add anywhere other than the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Monte I had a feeling that was the case and was working toward that direction